# Stuck trying to remove Certificate Authority role from a Windows 2019 AD domain controller

Tags: windows-server-2019, certificate-authority

I am trying to remove the Certificate Authority role from a Windows 2019 AD domain controller and am stuck at Step 5, Item 4 "Delete the private key that is associated with the CA" of the following MS KB article:
[How to decommission a Windows enterprise certification authority and remove all related objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/decommission-enterprise-certification-authority-and-remove-objects)
I can't get passed the following error:
`CertUtil: -delkey command FAILED: 0x80090016 (-2146893802 NTE_BAD_KEYSET) CertUtil: Keyset does not exist`
Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?
Here are my commands:

```
  C:\Users\theadmin>certutil -shutdown
  CertUtil: -shutdown command completed successfully.
    
  C:\Users\theadmin>certutil -getreg CA\CSP\Provider
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\CertSvc\Configuration\bennett-SYDDC03-CA\CSP:
    Provider REG_SZ = Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider
  CertUtil: -getreg command completed successfully.

  C:\Users\theadmin>certutil -CSP KSP -Key
  Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider:
  bennett-SYDDC03-CA-Xchg(365)
  4d183c7256e5a7ea7f353e66e42df2e3_ae2176ee-5d82-4797-a135-97e409c6ec69
  RSA
    AT_KEYEXCHANGE

  iisCngWasKey
  597367cc37b886d7ee6c493e3befb421_ae2176ee-5d82-4797-a135-97e409c6ec69
  SP800_108_CTR_HMAC
  KEY_DERIVATION

  bennett-SYDDC03-CA
  9cbcfcd7540d895eab9505d386b02142_ae2176ee-5d82-4797-a135-97e409c6ec69
  RSA
    AT_KEYEXCHANGE

  iisCngConfigurationKey
  f0e91f6485ac2d09485e4ec18135601e_ae2176ee-5d82-4797-a135-97e409c6ec69
  SP800_108_CTR_HMAC
  KEY_DERIVATION

  CertUtil: -key command completed successfully.

  C:\Users\theadmin>certutil -delkey "bennett-SYDDC03-CA"
  CertUtil: -delkey command FAILED: 0x80090016 (-2146893802 NTE_BAD_KEYSET)
  CertUtil: Keyset does not exist

  C:\Users\theadmin>certutil -delkey "bennett-SYDDC03-CA-Xchg(365)"
  CertUtil: -delkey command FAILED: 0x80090016 (-2146893802 NTE_BAD_KEYSET)
  CertUtil: Keyset does not exist'
```

Comment: Sounds like keys are already deleted, only container references are left, so you can move to next step in CA decommissioning process.

Comment: I hope this is the case. Thank you Crupt32 :)
Do you know if there is a way I can confirm that there are no keys still remaining?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have *Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider* as provider you also need to add *-CSP KSP* to the delete command for it to be succesful.

`certutil -CSP KSP -delkey CertificateAuthorityName`

In your case:

`certutil -CSP KSP -delkey "bennett-SYDDC03-CA"`

Comment: Good catch, even MS docommentatiot missed this thing. Could you clarify, what exactly private key is deleted with this command. I could guess that CA's private key, but when I delete this key I can perfectly see CA's private key via certificates mmc console. Even this mentioned MS doc says, that when I'll uninstall CA services I'll be left with CA's public and private keys.